# Who's timezone do I set - user's or mine?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm developing web app in codeigniter which has a heavy usage of date and time. What i need to know is who's timezone we need to set (i use configuration autoload to do it)? Mine or each user needs to set theirs? or server time zone (and find out from hostgator)?...

Comment: For storing in table use `timestamp` and for displaying use user's

Answer (score 1):

Use timezone based on user's location

in config file write

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

Comment: if i set date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');, will it automatically adjust itself if a london user comes in?

Comment: that is not possible. We find the location using IP or something then set default timezone